# Error while creating my first data pipeline

Tags: python, error-handling, airflow, helper

So whenever i am creating a simple data pipeline in vs code

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
while DAG(dag_id ='simple_dag') as dag:
    None
```

I am getting an error

```
Warning :root:OS Error while attempting to symlink the latest log directory.
```

Comment: Please check where you are creating the dag, it should be under airflow/dags folder.

Comment: fix it by correcting the socket volume path, 
In windows the volume will go with a double bar like this:
volumes:
  - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock